# MongoDB: Querying set of sub docs by _id

Tags: mongodb

Collection:

```
[
{
   tracks: [{_id: 'xxx', title: 'track x'}, {_id: 'yyy', title: 'track y'}
},
{
   tracks: [{_id: 'zzz', title: 'track z'}, {_id: 'ttt', , title: 'track t'}
}
]
```

I want to get result set that contains only tracks with id xxx and zzz:

```
tracks: [{_id: 'xxx'}, {_id: 'zzz'}
```

I tried with aggregation framework:

```
{$unwind : "$tracks" },
{$match: {'tracks._id': {$in:['xxx', 'zzz']}} }
```

But it returns empty set []

The strange thing for me is that if I try to match by another (field not _id), it works

```
{$unwind : "$tracks" },
{$match: {'tracks.title': {$in:['track x', 'track x']}} }
```

How can I accomplish my task?

P.S. I use mongoose.js framework to make a queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've figured out the problem: to select by _id one need to explicitly cast id values to native ObjectId type.

```
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId
...
{$unwind : "$tracks" },
{$match: {'tracks._id': {$in:[ObjectId('5140a09be5c703ac2c000002'), ObjectId('5140a09be5c703ac2c000002')]}} }
```

I think it is a bug, I created an issue in mongoose.js repo.

UPD. Answer on the issue from mongoose.js contributors:
At this time, arguments are not cast to the schema because $project operators allow redefining the "shape" of the documents at any stage of the pipeline.
- The documents returned are plain javascript objects, not mongoose documents cast to this models schema definition (since any shape of document can be returned).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your query it should just work (hovever I have never used mongoose). But you can try to use `find()` with projection to achieve the similar result:

```
db.tracks.find(
  { 'tracks._id': { $in: [ 'xxx', 'zzz' ] } }, 
  { _id: 0, 'tracks.title': 0, tracks: { $elemMatch: { _id: { $in: [ 'xxx', 'zzz' ] } } }
)
```

Comment: No find won't work for this scenario (I need array of tracks as a result). First, find it will anyway select base collection document (not track). Second, $elemMath selects only ONE document (sub document) matching the condition.

Comment: Got it, but anyway this is very strange that your `aggregate` query returns empty set, I've tried it and it works. Did you try this query from mongo console?

Comment: I've figured out the problem, mongoose happened not to implicitly convert string representation of objectId to native type.